# a contour integration involving $5$th roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\gamma$ be the circle of radius $2$ with centre at the origin in
>   the complex plane oriented in the anti-clockwise direction, then the
>   integral $$\oint_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z-3)(z^5-1)}$$ equals
>
> $(a)$ $\displaystyle{\frac{2\pi i}{3^5-1}}$.
>
> $(b)$ $\displaystyle{\frac{2\pi i}{3^4-1}}$.
>
> $(c)$ $\displaystyle{-\frac{2\pi i}{3^5-1}}$.
>
> $(d)$ $0$.

Clearly by Rouche's theorem, all the zeroes of $z^5-1$ lies on the circle $|z|=1$. So if we count those zeroes by $z_k$ where $k=0,1,2,3,4$ we have, by Residue theorem $$\oint_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z-3)(z^5-1)}=-\frac{2\pi i}{5}\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{1}{3{z_k}^4-1}$$ which is a nightmare to simplify algebraically. Can someone help in this regard if I have done something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: on a side note, rouche's theorem was overkill. if $z^5-1-0$, then $z^5=1$, so obviously they lie on $|z|=1$

Comment: My side note, as this is complex analysis, I usually think everything complex..:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. By using the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity) we have that
$$\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{dz}{(z-3)(z^5-1)}=-2\pi i(\text{Res}(f,3)+\text{Res}(f,\infty)).
$$
and those two residues are quite easy to evaluate for $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-3)(z^5-1)}$.

Recall that on the Riemann sphere, the algebraic sum of the complex residues of a meromorphic function is zero. See also the [Inside-Outside Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inside-OutsideTheorem.html).

Comment: Why would I calculate the residue at $z=3$, whereas this point lies completely outside $\gamma$? Also why do I need that residue at infinity?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: what the heck! how that would've helped ME during my analysis class. +1!